# Can't subtract dates because IDE considers one to be unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I am comparing two days, one is today's date and one is from a large list. The IDE seems to think item[3] is a unicode date, so I added print statements to show the results. The code is part of a large set but I included the important parts.

Code:

```
print today
print item[3]
if (today - item[3]).days > 10:
        item[4] =  today + timedelta(days=10)
```

Here are the results of the print statement:

```
2015-01-11 00:00:00
2015-01-06
```

Error Code:

```
if (today - item[3]).days > Configuration_SLA:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'unicode'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `item[3]` is a string (of the Unicode persuasion), turn it into a `datetime.datetime` object with `.strptime`:

```
theday = datetime.datetime.strptime(item[3], '%Y-%m-%d')
if (today - theday).days > 10:
    # etc, etc
```

I don't think your IDE has anything to do with it -- looks like it's just relaying a correct error message from Python itself (the one that would emerge if you were trying to do arithmetic between a `datetime.datetime` instance and any kind of string!).

BTW, when you want to look at things that may not be what they seem, **always** use

```
print repr(thefunnything)
```

which will give you more information, **never** just

```
print thefunnything
```

whose mission is just to display a human-readable string, not help debugging:-)

Comment: Thanks, really helpful. I added your line and got `ValueError: time data '%Y-%m-%d' does not match format '2015-01-06`

Comment: Yeah, I always swap the two args to `strptime` -- edited the A to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers that you saw doesn't mean it's a `datetime` object or integer. For example,

```
>>> a="4"
>>> print (a)
4
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

You see `4` but this doesn't mean 4 is here as an integer, it's string. So you should check your list, debug it like;

```
print (type(item[3]))
```

Comment: that made sense and the type is useful